# How do I adjust landscape tables in this journal template?

Tags: tables, landscape, journal-publishing, journal

I am trying to design landscape tables within a journal template (jfm.cls). Here is an example table:

[image: Long table]

There are two issues with this table:

- The journal automatically adds a toprule and bottomrule to any table environments. However, these rules are not properly adjusted to the landscape format.
- The margins are not properly adjusted for the landscape format, as you can see the caption almost touches the header.

The constraint is that I'd like to work without altering the journal template. The minimal code that generates the table and document is:

```
\documentclass{jfm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\title[This is a short title]{This is a long title}
\author[This is the author name]{}
\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccp{5cm}}
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccp{5cm}}
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

To compile, you will need the journal class, [which I've uploaded to the pastebin here.](http://pastie.org/private/2xbckrlgde2mnjvkz2log) You would need to download and rename to jfm.cls and put in the same folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the caption is the real problem. If it's width (or height ;-)) would be reduced, the rules with fit better into the landscape parameters

Comment: I was able to go into the journal style and simply change \textwidth to \linewidth in their ruler macro for the tables, and this sorts out the first problem. However, the second problem (with needing a reduction of the width of the text in landscape with respect to the headers) still exists. I tried to use the \newgeometry command but the geometry package does not play nice with the journal template. Thoughts?

Comment: Is there any news her?